How to close an anonymously opened file in Julia
As mentionned in the title, how can I close a file in the julia REPL which is opened anonymously, as follows :
jldopen("path/to/file.extension", "r")

I am using the JLD2 package for the concerned file, hence the jldopen() function.
Since this package is usable alongside FileIO, functions like close() can work but they don't accept the path string as an argument, they need a file type argument.
Is it just bad manners to anonymously open a file and I should never do it, or does it exist some way to close it anyway without restarting the REPL ?

Are you not doing anything with the return value of jldopen? The JLD2 documentation clearly states that the returned file object can (and should) be closed by calling close(f) on it. If I saw this function call in code where the return value was not used, I would be mystified as to why you are opening the file in the first place.

Yup I just wondered if there was a way to close a file when opened this way, but I'm aware that that's not really good practice
So it's mostly about curiosity

you didn't catch a reference to the object, so there's no way to use the object. I can't imagine that being useful in any programming language, except for side effects of the object's constructor.

If you're using the do syntax it's closed automatically
jldopen("path/to/file.extension", "r") do file
  # e.g. readlines(file)
end


That's right ! So basically there's no way to close a file when opened anonymously in one line, except by restarting the REPL
Thanks !
